# Changing object state in const method

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constants

I have class that resembles this:

```
class A{
    std::string tmp;
public:
    const std::string &doSomething() const{
       tmp = "something";
       return tmp; 
    }
};
```

It is very important the method `doSomething()` to be `const` and to return reference instead of the string itself.

Only way I see is to do it with dynamic allocation, e.g. something like:

```
class A{
    MyClass *tmp = new MyClass();
public:
    const MyClass &doSomething() const{
       *tmp = "something";
       return *tmp; 
    }
};
```

`tmp` variable "placeholder" is used ONLY inside `doSomething()`.

Is there some other, clear, better way to do this kind of temp value storage?

Comment: Why not `const std::string&`?

Comment: That is a very bad idea. You should consider re-designing that class.

Comment: @cad typo, will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mutable` modifier on `std::string tmp`:

```
class A {
  mutable std::string tmp;
  ...
}
```

This would allow a `const` method to modify that member.

Comment: And that would be a terrible idea.

Comment: Using a tool supported by the language exactly for the purpose meant to be used for?

Comment: `mutable` isn't really meant for that. But if OP wants to write bad code, that is their problem. It is still a terrible idea to have a `const` method break the logical constness of an object. And it is probably an XY problem anyway.

Comment: Mutable is exactly meant for that, §7.1.1: _The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a `const` specifier applied to the containing class object
and permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is `const`_. If the OP requires to be able to modify a temporary class member from a `const` method, that's exactly the purpose of `mutable`. If the `tmp` variable is irrelevant for the state of the object itself then it makes totally sense to use it. This is an XY problem, and I answered to the question, since the original intent is unknown.

Comment: That is like saying that the purpose of `new` is to create memory leaks. `mutable` is meant for state-changing operations that do not change the logical constness of an object.

Comment: Which is the case of a temporary derived state variable or a cache object.

Comment: `tmp` is a data member. It really is part of the object. Anyway, I appreciate you're answering to OP's strange requirements, and I already commented to them directly that doing this kind of thing is a bad idea.

Comment: I totally agree with you with the fact that mutable can be used as a bad design choice, I answered by suggesting it just because it's doesn't look like the OP is really interested in good design but just a solution. In any case mutable has a precise nique of application and it's perfect for that specific purpose (being/not being it the one of the OP, which is still unclear).

Comment: thanks. tmp is part of tje class, but is really not part of the state. It is merely placeholder for short term storage of the result. When I read mutable documentation, it looks it was created for exactly the purpose I want to use it. My real code is not for strings, but for operator->() inside custom iterator. I also want it const, because of template function that uses same iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `mutable` keyword for declaring `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to modify the attribute, you should quit the const qualifier of the method signature:

std::string& doSomething() { ... }

If you don't want to modify it, and you want to ensure that the method returns whatever you are waiting to receive:

const std::string& doSomething() const {...}

returning a const reference is the best way to ensure that the reference doesn't change of value. But without the const qualifier before the return type also should work well because of the second const qualifier (which specifies that the method shouldn't modify the current object)

In conclusion, I'm completely agree with @juanchopanza
Cheers