# c++ add flag to a const method

Tags: c++, constants

I have some class for a collector, and there are 2 methods, for example:

```
bool MyCollectorChanged() const;
bool MyCollectorDoSomeOperation() const;
```

I can't change the signatures of these methods which means I can't remove the `const` from the signature.

I want to set/unset some flag in `MyCollectorChanged()` for some situation, so I could check the flag value inside `MyCollectorDoSomeOperation()`.

Adding a member flag to the class will not work, as `MyCollectorChanged()` is a const method so I can't change the member flag inside `MyCollectorChanged()`.

Is there an option to do it? How can I set/unset some flag inside `MyCollectorChanged()`, so it will be visible inside `MyCollectorDoSomeOperation()`?

Comment: overload the method without `const`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/does-the-mutable-keyword-have-any-purpose-other-than-allowing-the-variable-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing object state in const method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596437/changing-object-state-in-const-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you have the option of changing the attributes of the `private` member variables, you can make some of them `mutable`. Then, you will be able to change their values in a `const` member function.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv for more info.

**Option 2**

If you have option of using the [Pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), you will be able to change the value of any member variable in the `class/struct` that represents the data of the main `class`.

Comment: How about overloading the method by removing `const`? Will it work?

Comment: @CinCout, I think the OP wants to update the data in the `const` member functions.

Comment: Agreed. But is overloading a possible solution to achieve the same? To set/reset flag in the non-const method, and call the `const` one from the non-const one to avoid code duplicacy?

Comment: @CinCout, that would work if the function is called on a non-`const` object but won't work if the function is called on a `const` object.